Unable to change Locale settings on Postgres@16 on Mac
I've installed PostgreSQL 16 via homebrew, which result installed at /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@16.
The default database was initialised via homebrew, so I had no chance to setup the locale which - as per the conf file - is the to C (or Current as I can read).
As my system is set to French, all messages are spit out in the same language even after the lc_* entries was replaced by a en_GB (and server restarted).
I've tried, without success to update the pg_database table and set datctype = 'en_GB.UTF-8' and datcollate='en_GB.UTF-8' for the postgres and the two templates database without success.
Is this because the default DB has to be reinitialised from scratch, or what?
If so, what should be done that am I currently missing?
